# Google Maps iOS SDK - Search for places in specific location

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, mapkit, google-places-api, google-places

I am using Google Maps and let user to move pin to any place.

After that I want get a list of places in selected area.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use json to fetch the places that close to the selected area.

Here is a link that teach you how to do it.

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search

Set the parameters that satisfy your search

For example:

location -> your selected area coordinate